# Altering table while publish dacpac file in sql

Tags: visual-studio, cicd

I have created a dacpac file in visual studio, in repo and azure sql there are two identical columns containing data, and I want to rename the column so that the data content is preserved

In sql:
dbo.TestAccount( AccountName,id)

In repo:
dbo.TestAccount(AccountName2,id)

I would like the AccountName column in sql to be renamed automatically to AccountName2 in the repo during publish (say using an alter table alter column).